# In which control I can add multiple values in Xamarin.Forms XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

After clicking on the "+" button I want to allow the user to add another value. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: have a look my image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVbvf.png

Comment: there isn't a built in control like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a horizontal `StackLayout`, and when you click a button, you add a child object to your `StackLayout` right behind your add button.

XAML `StackLayout`:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="layout" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Image="plus.png" Clicked="ButtonClicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

C# `ButtonClicked` event:

```
void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var newItem = ...; // create a new layout item

    // insert the new item right before the button in the stacked layout
    layout.Children.Insert(layout.Children.Count - 1, newItem);
}
```